# How to resume a continuation ensuring that the result is delivered on the MainActor?

Tags: swift, async-await, continuations, structured-concurrency

I have a continuation:

```
func a() async -> Int {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        continuation.resume(returning: 3)
    }
}
```

I would like all callers of this function to receive the result on the MainActor. I wouldn't like the caller to have to explicitly specify this rescheduling. I don't want this:

```
func c() async {
    let three = await a()
    await MainActor.run {
        b(three)
    }
}
```

What I instead want is for the entire code after returning to be performed on the MainThread until the next suspension point, something like this:

```
func c1() async {
    let three = await a()

    b(three) // Guaranteed main thread, although nothing speaks of it here
}
```

In a way, I want `a` to declare that `I return only on main actor!`, like this:

```
func a() @MainActor async -> Int {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        continuation.resume(returning: 3)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to even do this?

**UPDATE:**
Both commenters have suggested that I annotate the enclosing functions `c` and `c1` with `@MainActor`.

```
@MainActor
func c() async {
    let three = await a()
    await MainActor.run {
       b(three)
    }
}
```

This doesn't do it like I need it. It says:

- every time I await somebody, they must return on the main thread

But what I need instead is this:

- every time somebody awaits me, they must get my result on the main thread

Comment: Annotate the function with @MainActor.

Comment: `@MainActor func a() async -> Int { ... }`

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the comments, but they unfortunately don't solve the problem I'm talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

If you await some function, you can decide on which thread will it return.
But being an await-able function, you can not make sure that your result will be delivered to the caller on a particular and/or main thread.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible like this:

```
func a() async -> Int {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        Task {@MainActor in
            continuation.resume(returning: 3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh...? Did you actually test this code? Does `a` always return on main thread in this case?